# TCPDF MultiCell ignores valign if HTML is used

Tags: php, tcpdf

I can't figure out how to get vertically centered HTML text.
TCPDF seems to ignore the valign setting in MultiCell(). Depending on the $isHTML variable I get either centered "<b>Text</b>" ($isHTML=false), or bold "Text" ($isHTML=true) which is moved to the top of the cell.
Is there any way to achieve this?

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->SetFillColor(255,255,255);

$fill = 1;
$ln = 1;
$pos = ""; $reseth = true; $stretch = 0; $autopadding = false; $height = 32;

$isHTML = true;
$valign = "M";
$text = "<b>Text</b>";

$pdf->MultiCell(32, $height, $text, 1, "C", $fill, $ln, $pos, $pos, $reseth,$stretch, $isHTML, $autopadding, $height, $valign);

$pdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 0):

That parameter is not meant to be used directly. It's behavior is not well defined when you set it yourself. (The exact wording from the documentation is quoted below.) Instead, use `writeHTMLCell` or `writeHTML` if you need HTML.

> @param $ishtml (boolean) INTERNAL USE ONLY -- set to true if $txt is HTML
>   content (default = false). *Never set this parameter to true, use
>   instead writeHTMLCell() or writeHTML() methods.*

If the only thing you're doing is bolding the text, you could also just use `setFont` before your `multiCell` call.